# Carousel Boostrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, carousel

Ola. Estou tentando fazer pela primeira vez um carousel utilizando Bootstrap.

O carousel fica somente na primeira imagem, ele não muda automaticamente e nem quando clico nos botões laterais.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/style.css">
    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/carousel.js"></script>

    <title>Cartão</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid" id="sessionOne">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1">
                <img src="midia/img/logo-topo.png" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                <p>Baixe o App</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                <p>Perguntas Frenquentes</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Solicite aqui<br />o seu cartão</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Slider -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="slider">
            <!-- Topo do slide -->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="carousel-bounding-box">
                <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">

                    <!-- Carousel items -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0">
                        <img src="midia/img/carousel1.png"></div>

                        <div class="item" data-slide-number="1">
                            <img src="midia/img/carousel1.png"></div>

                        <div class="item" data-slide-number="2">
                            <img src="midia/img/carousel2.png"></div>

                        <div class="item" data-slide-number="3">
                            <img src="midia/img/carousel3.png"></div>
                    </div>

                            <!-- Carousel nav -->
                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                    </a>                                
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--/Slider-->


</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.hide-bullets {
list-style: none;
margin-left: -40px;
margin-top: 20px;
}
```

JS:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $('#myCarousel').carousel({
                interval: 1000
        });

        $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-0').html());

        //Handles the carousel thumbnails
       $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
            var id = this.id.substr(this.id.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);
            var id = parseInt(id);
            $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
        });
});
```

Não sei onde estou errando, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Grato!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adiciona esse script ANTES DE QUALQUER CÓDIGO JS

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js

Comment: Olá, @leonardo. Obrigado pela resposta... Inseri o script JQuery mas continua na mesma  :/

Comment: Certifique-se de inserir este script dentro da tag HEAD e os demais depois do footer. Inspeciona o elemento, vai no console, atualiza a página e manda um print.

Comment: Inseri no final do código, antes de </body> e funcionou, começou  a passar os slides... Mas ta passando rápido demais, tipo, uma imagem por segundo... Mudei o valor do campo interval de 1000 para 5000 e continuou na mesma velocidade de transição... Não é o campo interval que define o tempo para tansição de slide?

Comment: Ah, agora foi, sem querer eu tinha apagado a abertura de chave { ... kkkkk

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda @Leonardo!!

Comment: Opa, por nada. Boa sorte nos estudos @Gabriel